# Erro 404 ao inserir dados no banco usando PHP com WampServer

Tags: php, wampserver

Estou com o seguinte código que insere na minha DB um nome e cidade utilizando PHP.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin");
mysqli_select_db($link, "crud");
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" action="" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td>Insira o Nome</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="t1"</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Insira a Cidade</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="t2"</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Cadastrar"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit1"]))
{
    mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table1 values('$_POST[t1]', '$_POST[t2]')");
}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Toda vez que tento inserir, eu recebo o erro "404" no meu navegador.

Comment: Você deve colocar o attr action do form, para uma pagina php, que pegara os dados e irá inserir no banco

Comment: obrigado pela resposta colega, mas porque eu teria que redirecionar a página? a inserção esta sendo feita em: "if(isset($_POST["submit1"]))
{
    mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table1 values('$_POST[t1]', '$_POST[t2]')");
}
"

Comment: O erro ocorre após a inserção ?

Comment: ele da erro 404 conforme a imagem: [IMG]http://i65.tinypic.com/ip3yvd.png[/IMG]

Comment: Desculpa, eu editei sem querer no código, mas na realidade eu estou, inclusive ja editei o código no quote, por outro lado o erro persiste :/

Comment: Considere revisar seu código linha por linha, e corrija os erros de sintaxe primeiro.

Comment: Percebo que a porta padrão do wampserver é 3306, porém a porta mostrada na url da página quando tento executar o código via phpStorm é 63342, será que poderia ser isso? e como faço pra alterar isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos por partes. Quando você instala o wampserver (no windows) é criada uma pasta em `C:\wampserver`. Nessa pasta há uma chamada `www` (`C:\wampserver\www`) que equivale a você chamar pelo navegador a url `http://localhost` (por padrão na porta 80, que o navegador omite, mas seria algo como `http://localhost:80`). Então, se você colocar o seu arquivo, por exemplo chamemos de `inserir.php`, dentro da pasta `C:\wampserver\www`, você poderia acessar pelo navegador algo como `http://localhost/inserir.php` e tudo funcionaria corretamente.

A parte em que você diz que a porta padrão do wampserver é 3306, você deve estar se referindo a porta padrão do servidor de banco de dados mysql.

Para você executar o codigo diretamente do phpstorm algumas configurações deve ser feitas. Alguns links sobre como fazer essas configurações:

- [Documentação phpstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/)
- [Configurando phpstorm com xampp](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Instalando+e+configurando+o+XAMPP+com+o+PhpStorm) (basta desconsiderar a parte de xampp)
- [Configure phpstorm with wampserver](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207065475-How-to-configure-PHPStorm-to-work-with-WAMPServer-)

Comment: Meu caro Juven_v, você acertou em cheio!, pena que não posso honrar sua resposta por ser iniciante nesta comunidade, porém, é exatamente isso, minha dúvida foi solucionada quando configurei um interpretador manual para o phpStorm. Caso alguém mais passe pelo mesmo problema, este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=953mNQ5KuBI, me ajudou!